# \usepackage[caption] adding extra colon symbols in figure caption - latex

Tags: captions

I am trying to add caption in my figure in `latex` like this;

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, skip=10pt}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5in]{figures/python.png}
  \caption[Python]{Python \cite{python}}
  \label{fig:python}
\end{figure}
```

But it is adding two colons like this;

[image: Caption]

If I remove this package `\usepackage{caption}`, it works fine but then this package `\captionsetup[table]{font=small, skip=10pt}` does not work.

What am I missing here??

Comment: Is the `aitthesis` document class available online?

Comment: @Mico I've updated the document class. And changing `subfig` to `subcaption` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Actually it didn't. Issue is still there. I tried with and without `\captionsetup[table]{font=small`

Comment: Having the same problem, have you ever solved this?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this Package 
`\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,skip=10pt]{subfig}`